# Why does a divs top margin move multiple divs down?

Tags: html, css

Say I have 3 divs side by side:

```
<body>
    <div id="ok1">Content for  id "ok1" Goes Here</div>
    <div id="ok2">Content for  id "ok2" Goes Here</div>
    <div id="ok3">Content for  id "ok3" Goes Here</div>
</body>
```

Then I apply a margin to one of them:

```
#ok1 {
    display: inline-block;   
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#ok2 {
    display: inline-block; 
}

#ok3 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Why is it that all three get a top margin?

Comment: Combining `display: inline` and `display:inline-block` can do some pretty funny things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An inline formatting context is established between the elements, therefore the following applies:

> **[9.4.2 Inline formatting contexts](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting)** (w3.org)
>
> In an inline formatting context, boxes are laid out horizontally, one after the other, beginning at the top of a containing block. Horizontal margins, borders, and padding are respected between these boxes. The boxes may be aligned vertically in different ways: their bottoms or tops may be aligned, or the baselines of text within them may be aligned. The rectangular area that contains the boxes that form a line is called a line box.

The default `vertical-align` value for `inline` elements is `baseline`.

You could change this value to something like `top`, thus changing the results [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/AZAnG/2/)

```
div { vertical-align:top; }
```

Comment: yes i do. i think they could have designed this much better though

Answer (score 2):

This is because the two divs are inline with the first one. When you did `display: inline-block;` it moved the other two divs into a block with the first one.

If you take that out, it goes back to normal.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HV2pA/)

*thanks to @MosheKatz for the idea on inline-block*